# Loopback/mongodb: find all jobs that share a certain skill

Tags: mongodb, loopback4

I have a collection of jobs that have certain skills. Please see the pic below.

[image]

As you can see each "job" object has a "skills" array. Skills are shared between different jobs, thus I need to write a get request, so that when a user clicks a skill, it shows different jobs that require this skill. Could you please help me with that.  I wrote a code but it does not work.

There are 32 documents overall, each document looks something like this. It has a job name and array of skills.

Some jobs share the same skills. For example IT Business Analyst and Business Analyst.

[image]
[image]

While some jobs share only jew ones. For example, Business Analyst and Technical Manager share "Communication" skill.

[image]
[image]

An output is array of documents that share the same skill. For example array of "Business Analyst" and "Teachnical Manager" objects since they share "Communication" skill.

```
[
  {
    "name": "Business Analyst",
    "category": "Analyze",
    "skills": [
      {
        "name": "Listener",
        "id": "1"
      },
      {
        "name": "Critical Thinking",
        "id": "2"
      },
      {
        "name": "Problem Solving",
        "id": "3"
      },
      {
        "name": "Analytical",
        "id": "4"
      },
      {
        "name": "Communication",
        "id": "5"
      },
      {
        "name": "Documentation",
        "id": "6"
      },
      {
        "name": "Research",
        "id": "7"
      }
    ]
  },
{
    "name": "Technical Manager",
    "category": "Management",
    "skills": [
      {
        "name": "Team Management",
        "id": "8"
      },
      {
        "name": "Mentorship",
        "id": "9"
      },
      {
        "name": "Decision Making",
        "id": "10"
      },
      {
        "name": "Strategic Thinking",
        "id": "11"
      },
      {
        "name": "Negotiating",
        "id": "12"
      },
      {
        "name": "Communication",
        "id": "5"
      },
      {
        "name": "Financials",
        "id": "13"
      }
    ]
  }

]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very basic query, i wonder how you didnt get that.

```
db.getCollection('skills').find({"skills.name":"Communication"})
```

Or by skill ID if it is unique

```
db.getCollection('skills').find({"skills.id":"5"})
```